# How to create object using facebook graph api, for unity games?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I'm learning how to use facebook graph API in unity3d game, for creating object to use them in asking gifts from friends playing the game, sending a challenge to invite to play.

I tried to add them using graph API,

```
{
 "app_id":29xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
 "type":"testapp:life",
 "url":"https:\/\/apps.facebook.com\/appname",
 "title":"Life",
 "description":"Use this life to play another time!"
}
```

got below result,

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "fbtrace_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
  }
}
```

I also tried using the c# script

```
var formDict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
 {
   {"title", "Life"},
   {"type", "testapp:life"},
   {"app_id", "29xxxxxxxxxxxx"}
 };
var formData = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "object", Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Serialize(formDict) } };
FB.API("/me?objects/testapp:life", HttpMethod.POST, CreateFBLifeCallback, formData);
```

and getting below error in the log,

```
{"error":{"message":"(#10) Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"XXXXXXXXXXX"}}
```

Still unable to create the object. And a bit confused that which method should I use to create an object? or am I doing something wrong?

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: looks like a custom og object/action, but they are deprecated. where did you read about this?

Comment: And even if this was still a thing, the path should probably be `/me/objects`, and not `/me?objects`

Comment: thanks @luschn I read it on some blog. Then how can I use pre-defined objects for my purpose?

thanks @04FS I tried both `/me/objects` and `/me?objects`

Comment: did you even check out the official docs yet? > https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions/

Comment: yes, but I am unable to find how to use them for unity, c# code.